# Website fails to load correctly on specific network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, 3g

A website I'm trying to access fails to load properly when I'm on my home network, regardless of device or browser, but loads just fine over my phone's 3g connection.

The site will show as connected and begin to download the content, but will do so for a very very long time, often failing mid-way, whereas all other websites will load instantly.

The curious thing though is that the site loads instantly while I'm connected to the internet via my phone's 3g, but the very second I connect my phone to the home Wi-Fi, it too begins to load that site unbearably slowly.

I've tried letting the site load for over 20 minutes, and some elements on the page as small as 12 kb will *fail* after downloading for 8 minutes. They all seem to have failed with a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error.

I'd like to point out that my home internet is 20 Mbps download and 3 Mbps upload, so the internet speed itself should be more than adequate. Especially considering the fact that I've used this site many times before without this issue.

I've tried to reboot my router, but that doesn't work either. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: There might be a routing error with your ISP, a problem with DNS lookups or your IP might be blocked by the website or the website could be blocked by your ISP. Without additional details it'd be impossible to tell. Can you post the output for traceroute and the URL of the website?

Comment: @mtak what exactly do you mean by "traceroute"?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute)

Comment: @gronostaj is it safe to post the traceroute? I mean it DOES display all the IP addresses it goes through